# How to get and use variables and parameters from .js in node.js server?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, server

i'm new at js so go easy on me.
my main goal is to get parameter from Message.js (an array named messages) and use them in the server. 
for this part just print them on the screen will do.

tnx to the helpers! :)

*my Message.js file look like this:*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       var messages = [
    {
        name: 'I am Message number one',   //a js field in an object(message in this case) and it's value after the semicolon
        texts: [                               //an array of 3 strings in js
            'mary had a little lamb',
            'hail hydra',
            'spider-man rocks'
        ],
        images: [                               //an array of 2 images in js
            'https://fb-s-c-a.akamaihd.net/h-ak-xat1/v/t1.0-9/10156120_630371003705480_8529510393733631385_n.png?oh=8412d9c3b69d39b6030d66f9709e1e1e&oe=58EEA4F2&__gda__=1492580526_84a87f898177ec43770cf3a5317fdb31',
            'https://fb-s-a-a.akamaihd.net/h-ak-xtf1/v/t1.0-9/10268685_630867936989120_785222708436272994_n.jpg?oh=c15c538b5385843ad0b44affda0f378c&oe=58B9EB5F&__gda__=1488430186_6c7c227a21e77492f092dc999834157d'
        ],
        times: [                       //array of vars initialized in Dates kind values
            {
                fromDate: new Date(2016, 0, 1),  //jan is 0, feb is 1, and so on...
                toDate: new Date(2016, 11, 31),
                fromTime: '09:00',
                toTime: '22:53',
                days: [0, 1, 5]    // sunday starts with a 0 then monday is 1 and so on...
            }
        ]
    }, //until here this is a one object of 'message'
    {
        name: 'I am Message number two',   //a js field in an object(message in this case) and it's value after the semicolon
        texts: [
            'soon in theaters',        //an array of 4 strings in js
            'the lion king is Simba',
            'tiom&pumba rules',
            'spider-man is awesome!'
        ]
         }];
         }
```

*and i don't know how to do the server's part* 
tried something like this:

```
    var http = require('http');
    var port = 8080;
    var fs = require("fs");



    const querystring = require("querystring");
    function onRequest(request, response){
       console.log("user made a request " + request.url);
       response.writeHead(200);
       response.write(messages[0].name);
       response.write("here is your data");
       response.toString(message[0]);
       response.end();

}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(port);
```

Comment: You are talking about server side only, or you want send this array from the client to server?

Comment: Did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41349459/how-to-get-and-use-variables-and-parameters-from-js-in-node-js-server/41349513#41349513) below answer your question? Any comments?

Comment: client to server. the main goal is to show a site that shows few messages without the need of reload so for this logic i used setInterval() 
to show the message from an html file that render and show those messages. now i'm trying to expand the project and also use a server that will get the data from the .js file and will send it to the client to render and show it.

Answer (score 0):

In `Message.js` change:

```
var messages = [ ...
```

to:

```
module.exports = [ ...
```

And the use it with:

```
var messages = require('./Message.js');
```

in some other files of your app.

If that file is not in the same directory then you may need to use:

```
var messages = require('../Message.js');
```

or:

```
var messages = require('../lib/Message.js');
```

or something like that, depending on where it is located from the point of view of the file that you want to `require` it in.

Answer (score 0):

In your Message.js add

```
exports.messages= messages; //add this after your messages array declaration
```

AND in your server...

```
var myMessages= require('./Message.js');

var messages= myMessages.messages;
```